# website problem

Tags: users, uri

I used to go to a website of an organization .www.nameofthewebsite.org. One day that website was not accessible,may be it could be on change.That time i thought something wrong with my browser.So i searched in google and gave a name in the url as www.nameofthewebsite.org/install.php,then it asked as install in english.I choosed english and it installed something,then it went to drupal website asking username and password.Now whoever public goes to the site it goes to drupal.And i fear it has been done by me.After sometime if i go the website it said site offline due to technical problems.I am not the admin.please help me,what happened when i gave install.php in the url?

Comment: Be more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed Drupal on a website you don't own. But in order to do this, the administrators must have taken some steps in advance. On an attempt to load install.php on a working (installed) website you will see:

> Drupal already installed
>
> - To start over, you must empty your existing
>     database.
> - To install to a different database, edit the appropriate
>     settings.php file in the sites folder.
> - To upgrade an existing
>     installation, proceed to the update script.
> - View your existing site.

So the administrators (or a malicious person) must have emptied the database of the existing site first. You had no way to remove the database (under normal circumstances) and you are not the reason the data is missing.

Comment: Is there a chance of misunderstanding me?Could they find my location?

Comment: There is a reasonable change your ip has been logged, so they might find or have that. But a spam bot or any other user that may have found the page would have hit the next button as well. I don't believe they can actually blame you for that (but I have no experience with legal issues). In the end they did not install Drupal properly as promoted in [PSA-2015-001](https://www.drupal.org/PSA-2015-001).